# i am getting null pointer exception while inserting data into sqlitedatabase using dbhelper

Tags: android, sqlite

when I insert record that time I face the below problem:
`java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo    java.lang.nullpointerexception`.I am getting null pointer exception while inserting values into sqlite database. The dh in `DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(this)` is coming out to be null when I try to check its value by putting a breakpoint. Below is the code of my DatabaseHelper class and the class from where I am trying to insert the values.

First Activity : DbActivity.java

```
package com.example.dbhelpersimple;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DbActivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_CNT = "contact";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "test";
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "PERSONS.db";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE test"+
            "(name VARCHAR(10), contact VARCHAR(10));";





    SQLiteDatabase db;





    public DbActivity(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }









    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addrecord(String name, String contact)
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COL_CNT, contact);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }


    void getrecords()
    {
        int i;
        //String query="SELECT * FROM test";
        Cursor c=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(c.isAfterLast()==false)
        {
            Log.d("Name", c.getString(0));
            Log.d("Contact", c.getString(1));
        }



    }


}
```

Second Activity: manipulateActivity.java

```
package com.example.dbhelpersimple;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class manipulateActivity extends Activity{

    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;

      EditText edt1,edt2;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);

            edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
            edt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextcontact);

    DbActivity dbact= new DbActivity(this);

    dbact.addrecord("sagar", "111");




     }

}
```

Comment: And it will probably give you a line number, tell us which line that is in the code you pasted also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First Activity* : **DbActivity.java**

```
private final Context context;

public DbActivity(Context context)
    {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

    }
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
               "create table test (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
               + "name text Not Null, contact text Not Null);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);


}
```

*Second Activity*: **ManipulateActivity.java**

```
private DbActivity dbHelper;

private Context context;

public ManipulateActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

 dbHelper = new DbActivity(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chang your DbActivity class constructor like below mention.

```
     public DbActivity(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       this.myContext = context;   // myContext is your context in DbActivity class
  }
```

I think you are not getting the context that's why you are getting null pointer exception.Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I think you have problem in database_create statement.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                   "create table test (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                   + "name text Not Null, contact text Not Null);";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much non-sense in that code. But, one after another:

In SQLite, there is no `VARCHAR`. This type is automatically converted to the type `TEXT`, which is outlined [in the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus
>   assigned TEXT affinity.

---

In your DatabaseHelper-class `onUpgrade()`-method, you have the following code:

```
db.execSQL(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Since your `DATABASE_NAME`-constant is just the name of the database file (and therefor not a valid SQL query), this will fail.

---

In your `addrecord()`-method, you're using a `SQLiteDatabase`-object, which is never initialized. This is the reason why you get your NPE.

To optain a read/writeable database form your `SQLiteOpenHelper`, use the [`getReadableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29)- and [`getWritableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29)-methods.

The reason why this problem occurs when your Activity is started is, that you're using this method in the Activities `onCreate()`-method, which is called when the Activity is created.

---

A working implementation of your `addrecord()`-method might look like this:

```
public void addrecord(String name, String contact){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COL_CNT, contact);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    db.close();
}
```